NVMe-oF, multipath and path failure handling
I am trying out setting up ZFS over network-shared device blocks using NVME-oF. I built it over RDMA using ConnectX-3 IB interfaces and TCP using a classic 10 Ethernet connection. NVMe's own multipath feature handles the two paths to the exported device and everything works well, until a path failure happen.
When I deactivate either the RDMA or TCP export, the initiator side reacts by shutting down the whole nvme device for 10s of seconds, before it brings it back with the surviving RDMA or TCP link. The problem is the long delay between link failure and the device being brought back on the initiator side. I would have expected the NVMe device to survive with no interruption, so long at least one link is still active, but this does not seem to be the case. I got this behaviour confirmed in some NVMe doc (section "Path Error Recovery"). I am not satisfied because if my ZFS pool is in use while such a failure happens, then all accesses to the pool filesystem hang, even after the NVMe device has been brought back online.
I tried to configure the system to not use NVMe's integrated multipath feature, but instead using DM multipath (adding nvme_core.multipath=N in the initiator's kernel cmdline and reboot), but I observe the same behaviour. I also try to export the same block device via distinct NVMe subsystems, ports and namespaces (not only distinct NVMe ports) and use DM multipath, but then the initiator seems to be able to setup only one NVMe device for the exported block device, instead of the expected 2, and so I cannot use multipath DM either.
At present, the multipath feature seems useless for fault tolerance. Is anyone aware of any workaround to the issue?
Using Debian Bookworm and Proxmox 8.2.4 as OS for both target and initiator.
